# Will two JPEG images with the same dimensions have the same header when created using GDI+?

Tags: c++, winapi, jpeg, gdi+

If I use the `Image::Save()` function to save two images as JPEG (with the same quality), and these two images have the same dimensions (width and height), will these two images have an identical header (which I noticed it to be 623 bytes)?

**Note:** my testing shows that they will indeed have an identical header, but is this guaranteed?

Comment: As I recall you can have comments and various metadata in a JPEG. Not sure if it's stored in the header. But why don't you just look up the format?

Comment: I doubt it's guaranteed. Why would it be?

Comment: @Cheers and hth Not sure what you mean by **"why don't you just look up the format"**, but what I want to do is basically save 1000s of images (with the same dimensions) as JPEG, and then remove the header from all of them and have only one header saved, and then when I want to display a JPEG image, I would just add this header to it.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization. How much is 623 bytes compared to the image size.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf The image size is less than 500 bytes.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Because I don't know what parameter(s) in the header can be different if the images have the same dimensions and I am using the same compression quality. I guess theoretically some images can have additional parameters, or some images can have different values for the **APPn** parameter!

Comment: If GDI+ uses the same Huffman tables for all images (which it probably does), then the headers will be identical.

Comment: This really sounds like premature optimization, or really, no optimization at all. If you are reading from disk, it doesn't matter whether it's going to be 500 bytes, or 1123 bytes. Both are lower than the physical sector size. The driver will probably read the entire sector anyway, so your savings are zero, and probably become negative once you start to fumble with the data. Don't optimize until profiling identified a bottle neck. If you are concerned about disk usage: Compare the *Size on disk* values for both files.

Answer (score 0):

I would never rely on the headers (or first 623 bytes) being the same in a JPEG image (except for the first 2 bytes, being `0xff` and `0xd8` - Start Of Image / `SOI`). Even if this is the case now, it could change in the future.

So basically you would be removing information from the image, which you would not be able to reassemble if that header changes.

There could be anything in those first 623 bytes. Even the order of `APPn` can be random.

It would be better to give each distinct block of header data a unique `ID` (or `MD5`), and store that `ID` where the header data was. That way, if the header changes in the future, you just store a different ID and you will always be able to reassemble the image. Or in case you're storing the images as `BLOB`s in a database, add a column with the header `ID`.

Also make sure you split the data on *full blocks* - blocks starting with markers (`0xff` `0xnn`) - the next two bytes contain the size of the block.

JPEG format: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf